# Cannot filter certain pivot table fields

Tags: excel

I'm using a worksheet that is configured to connect to the data Cube and everything I see is a pivot table.

I put Customer ID into Row and Net Revenue into Column, but somehow I cannot filter Revenue (it's greyed out), and I cannot use a slicer on that field. Is there anything I did wrong? I can filter Customer ID, but that's not going to be useful. It seems that I can only put it into "Values", which is pretty frustrating.

A side question: Is there a way to know the SQL scripts used in each OLAP query? I'm thinking maybe I can write VBA codes for the query, which would be more flexible.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to put Net Revenue on a column field. Can you elaborate on what it is you are trying to achieve? I take it you are trying to do this because you want to filter on customers with a net revenue above or below a certain amount?

Comment: Thanks @jeffreyweir you are right, I'm trying to filter customers that have  zero and negative (refund) revenue with us. I think I must have overlooked the option somewhere because it seems to be a simple one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the Customer ID filter icon, and select the VALUE filter option. This lets you filter the aggregated numbers in the VALUES field from the perspective of the field you are filtering from (in this case, from the perspective of the ID field)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tested on the sheet and it works! Just a side question, if I know some MDX, is it possible to filter-query the Cube and dump the data directly in the sheet? I think the majority of the time spent is on rendering in Excel and sorting/filtering. If I can do the sorting/filtering part during data fetching, that would improve the speed significantly.